# How to use a messagebox when an invalid directory is used with openfiledialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I'm trying to create a VERY VERY simple file browser just to keep my novice c# in practice and a project to expand upon later, but I can't seem to execute code when an invalid directory is entered. With my current code, it redirects to Documents. When I press cancel, it goes back to Documents. If I cancel again, it displays the error I specified.

My current code is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dir = textBox1.Text;
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = dir;
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    { 

    }
    else
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Please Choose a valid directory.");
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Change this line `if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` to this 
`if (result == DialogResult.OK)` also look at this example in the case they click Cancel as well http://www.dotnetperls.com/dialogresult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190792(v=vs.95).aspx), it displays the OpenFileDialog box, and you're calling it twice.

The first time, you store the user's selection in `result`, but do nothing else with it. You can hit OK or Cancel to this one - it makes no difference. You'll always get to the following line, which prompts the user again.

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

The second time, you actually test the result and take some action. Hopefully in a real app there'd be some further test for whether or not the directory is valid, other than just that the user pressed "Cancel".

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    ...
```

If you don't need `result` later on, I'd suggest just removing the first line.